# Array element shift

Tags: excel

I have a question. Sorry if it's very simple, I'm new to this and have struggled for several hours to do this without success.

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I am trying to divide the first element of a1 by the second element of a2, the second element of a1 by the third element of a2, the third element of a1 by the fourth element of a2, etc...it's a long list but this is a short form.

The new array or list should be something like this:

```
a3 = [(1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 5/6, 6/7, 7/8, 8/9, 9/10]
```

Here is my code:

```
a1_new = a1[:-1]

a2_new = a1[1:]

a3 = a1_new/a2_new
```

return a3

The answer is not correct.

What is a better way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  You show a desired result a string in the form of `[a/b,b/c,c/d,...]`  In Excel a numeric array constant would look like  `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` and if you were actually dividing one by the other: `{0.5,0.666666666666667,0.75,0.8,0.8333333333333333}`

Comment: Also, what version of Excel

Answer (score 0):

In **Excel 365**

```
={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}/{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
```

[image]